# Specifics of ESRI's use of FlexNet Publisher TrustedStorage at ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0

So at ArcGIS 10, ESRI adopted Flexera's **FlexNet Publisher Trusted Storage** module for secure exchange of license file "fulfillment records" and transfer of product activations.

Question what network traffic occurs and what corresponding firewall ports should be open to allow the traffic to pass? Also, what conflicts will arrise with other applications running the same FlexNet Publisher licensing tools--Autodesk, SolidWorks, Adobe, etc. and how best to make things coexist?

The FLexNet Publisher [License Administration Guide](http://www.globes.com/support/utilities/fnp_LicAdmin_11_9_1.pdf) doesn't address those specifics. And when looking at the ArcGIS 10 installations you'll now see a **FLEXNetLicensingService.exe** running and calls to **libFNP.dll** on license server and client. That in addition to the "old" FlexNet Publisher **lmgrd.exe** and ESRI's FlexNet **ARCGIS.EXE** Vendor daemon on the license server.

How does it all behave? And how do we fix it when collisions or version conflicts occur?

A very scary thing is that a number of Apps using FNP are placing configurations and executable files into the common directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Macrovision Shared\FLEXnet Publisher
```

Where vendors can do what they want and update their FlexNet components at their convenience, without regard for release level of other applications present on the system. Looking at the FLEXERA site I don't have a sense that they make much of an effort to support the end users. License exchanges over VPN has been especially troublesome for end users.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of questions there:
Question what network traffic occurs and what corresponding firewall ports should be open to allow the traffic to pass? 
**ports 27000–27009**

Use the Admin Tools (via Web Browser) to avoid conflicts it makes it easier to Manage Multiple Licenses in a mixed environment

Comment: Well yes, those well know ports and that aspect of FlexNet Publisher lmgrd/ARCGIS exchanges remain in place with the ArcGIS 10 LM as evidenced by the continued functionality for ArcGIS 9.x clients. As before, if a firewall is active on the server--the vendor daemon would have to bound to a port. Firewall exceptions: lmgrd -- 27000-27009, ARCGIS --> bound to a port > 1024 with PORT=xxxx appended to the VENDOR ARCGIS line of the service.txt file, the replacement for the license file. The unclear piece is the addition of Trusted Storage and the network exchanges to service that.